# Direct TCP/IP connections in P2P apps

Tags: networking, tcp, p2p

From a [Joel's post on Copilot](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/01/26.html):

> Direct Connect! We’ve always done
>   everything we can to make sure that 
>   Fog Creek Copilot can connect in any
>   networking situation, no matter  what
>   firewalls or NATs are in place. To
>   make this happen, both parties  make
>   outbound connections to our server,
>   which relays traffic on their  behalf.
>   Well, in many cases, this isn’t
>   necessary. So version 2.0 does 
>   something rather clever: it sets up
>   the initial connection through our 
>   servers, so you get connected right
>   away with 100% reliability. But then 
>   once you’re all connected, it quietly,
>   in the background, looks for a  way to
>   make a direct connection. If it can’t,
>   no big deal: you just keep  relaying
>   through our server. If you can make a
>   direct peer-to-peer  connection, it
>   silently shifts your data onto the
>   direct connection. You  won’t notice
>   anything except, probably, much faster
>   communication.

How do they change the server connection to a P2P connection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty tricky and interesting.  I'm sure I have some details wrong, but the overview is this:

The programs can already talk to each other through Joel's server, so they can exchange information with each other and Joel's server.  Further, Joel has their external IP addresses, and they give joel information about their internal IP addresses.

They decide to try this hole punch technique.  Computer A initiates a TCP connection with Computer B using B's external IP address.  It won't go through, but what it does is tell's A's router that it needs to allow incoming packets from B on a given port.

Computer B does the same thing, but its message gets through to A since A's router opened a port/ip combination that matches what B sent (there's some port magic that happens here - this is non trivial, but doable).

B's router remembers that B initiated a connection with A on a given port and IP, and so A's packets now flow into B past their router correctly as well.

So it's actually pretty straight forward, but the implementation has details, especially regarding how ports are given to new TCP connections, and how NAT routers *typically* deal with TCP requests and how they map to external ports.  These details are the interesting, and difficult, bit.

-Adam

Comment: So when A gets the IP of B, does it open up a new socket connection to B? or uses the same socket it used for connecting to the central server? I hope the latter isn't the case because then they have to sync their seq and ack numbers as well.

Comment: @FaizHalde the details are difficult and more than what is needed for this post. Please consider asking a new question to understand how the NAT hole punch method works

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique called "[Hole Punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking))" that works well with "Cone" NAT (Cone is a technical familly of router). That's not an 100% sure technique, today, it works well with UDP on about 80% of the router.

There is some implementations of library to realize Hole Punching: [STUN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stun/) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN))

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simple version is that they drop the server connection and replace it with the P2P connection.

Something along the lines of:

1. Machine1 connects to copilot's servers.
2. Machine1 connects to copilot's servers.
3. Machine1 connects to copilot's servers.
4. Machine2 subsequently connects, and they begin screen sharing.
5. Machine2 opens a port intended for Machine1 to connect to.
6. Machine1 tries to connect to the now open port on Machine2.

If this connection is established:

1. The connection to copilot's servers is severed.
2. Data is instead transfered over the direct (P2P) connection between the two machines.