# Does Wippien use a direct connection?

Tags: file, vpn, p2p, transfer, nat

I started using Wippien to make p2p connections between 2 distant Windows Servers. I use 2 different GMail Accounts.

Wippien uses "Mediators" to initiate the connection. But are mass data transfers really direct, or is it routed through the mediator?

I also found this article which seems related: [Direct TCP/IP connections in P2P apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205/direct-tcp-ip-connections-in-p2p-apps)

How can I find out if the connection is direct and how can I find out about speed?

The connection seems slow while I transfer files, but this is not measured but only my first impression.

Comment: I am now sure that this is absolutely slow. What can I do to improve speed? Can I open some port on the router?

Answer (score 1):

Wippien does use a direct connection.

It only uses servers for settings IP adresses and breaking through the firewall.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use a real VPN solution, something like OpenVPN for example.

Comment: I must say, i tried to set up a real VPN solution and without any links to guides or anything this is pretty much a useless comment.

Comment: Harsh. First Google result for "OpenVPN howto" tells you everything you need to know. http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html