# TCP connections between Android devices

Tags: android, tcp, udp, client-server

I am thinking of building Android apps that can communicate to each other - e.g. IM or game. As with any Java/Android, there is a suite of TCP/UDP communication library i can use.

Question is this: Android devices normally are connected via the Telco network, and Telcos normally have firewalls/NAT routers which makes direct connection to an Android device impossible.

Are there anyone out there who manage to use sockets to connect 2 devices directly ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205/direct-tcp-ip-connections-in-p2p-apps

Answer (score 0):

[STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) is usually used for NAT traversal. Might be a bit overkill though.

[Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html), [ServerSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and [DatagramSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) are for communication.